# Minimizing/Maximizing a Form leads to Multiple Comboboxes being set in Focus. What is happening here?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a form which can be minimized inside of a Parent Form using the Dock Property. The output looks like this. [image]

Upon maximizing the form multiple comboboxes are highlighted. The output looks like this.

[image]

From researching I found that multiple Controls can not remain focused at the same time in Windows Forms which makes me curious why this is happening.

**Information**:

The Comboboxes are Custom UserControls.

All Comboboxes are contained inside an TableLayoutPanel and all those contained inside another TableLayoutPanel.
I have tried the following thusfar to no avail:

- Setting the Form ActiveComponent Property to null
- Setting the UserControl ActiveComponent to null
- Calling Focus on one of the Comboboxes

**Result**: Problem Solved, Questions remain.

Upon removing the individual layer of TablelayoutPanels lead to this problem being resolved. I'm wondering why a hierarchy of TableLayoutPanels' affects the focus and why are multiple controls focusable to begin with.

Comment: Focus an Selection are two different things. You cannot have multiple Focused Control, you can have multiple Controls that have active Selections. Your ComboBoxes are probably coded to select the first item.

Comment: As I mentioned the problem is now resolved after removing the extra layer of TableLayoutPanels. Can someone shed some light on that? Or link to a related question? I seem to be running into an issue with **nested TableLayoutPanels** in other places too.